# Can I prevent the creation of non-temporary instances of my C++ class?

Tags: c++, temporary-objects

I'm building an expression-like class system.  I would like to take advantage of the lifespan rules for temporary variables to avoid storing the ensure expression in a giant ugly templated class with unreadable error messages.

Of course, if the user cleverly saves off one of my expression objects in a variable, they can accidentally create dangling temporaries.

Is there a way to prevent the user from being able to create a local variable to hold onto one of my expression instances, so that they can never be surprised by a temporary that they thought was captured but was actually just temporary?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen duplicates of this question here on SO, but I can't find any now. IIRC you can make it harder to accedentally store it, but not impossible if the person is determined enough.

Comment: I see one library solving that problem by splitting variable and tree-expression: So you construct the expression template which store placeholder and constant (and sub expression), then apply expression only at the end.

Comment: pre-c++17, you might have all constructors private (copy/move ones can either be deleted) and create a factory method using `return {..};`, but guaranty copy elision of C++17 breaks that.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a way of stopping someone from having a local of a type you allow them to create, but you can make it mostly unusable by `&&` qualifying all of it's members.

That won't stop a determined attempt to misuse it, as they can always `std::move` it, but it should avoid accidents.